# How to echo page number with codeigniter pagination library?

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, numbers, echo

I am using the codeigniter pagination library to page my search results. I am using a limit and an offset to generate the results.

I would like to know how, apart from in the pagination links, echo the number of the page the user is currently viewing.

For example;

You are currently viewing page X out of Y results.

How is this possible??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could extend the Pagination class (*system/libraries/Pagination.php*).

Create a file called **MY_Pagination.php** and put it in *application/libraries/*

Add this code to your extend pagination class;

```
class MY_Pagination extends CI_Pagination {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function current_place() {
        return 'You are currently viewing page '.$this->cur_page.' out of '.ceil(($this->total_rows/$this->per_page)). 'results';
    }
}
```

Don't forget to make sure the class extension prefix is set correctly to **MY_** in the *config.php* (about line 109)

Then you can access it in your controller like;

```
$current = $this->pagination->current_place();
```

Which you can pass into your view.

Comment: never hack the core libraries..you should only extend them

Comment: @Henesnarfel - have changed answer to remove 'hack' comment. Now shows doing it via extending native library,

Answer (score 4):

This also gives the current page no

```
$currentPage = floor(($this->uri->segment(n)/$config['per_page']) + 1);
```

where n is the segment

```
echo "Current Page:".$currentPage;
```

Comment: It says, Message: Use of undefined constant n - assumed 'n' :/

Comment: hello @deathlock in the place of 'n' you need to pass the segment no, replace 'n' with your segment no

Comment: @DevendraVerma I'm sorry I'm not really a programmer, but what is a "segment"? Tried to google "PHP segment" but doesn't find a good explanation

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are setting up the offset.  Ours is setup with an offset of the perpage.  So our default is 10 per page.  So for page one the offset is 0.  For page two the offset is 10 and so on.  So for me to get the current page I would take the offset divided by the current limit plus 1.  So `($cur_page/$per_page)+1` would get me the current page.

Comment: Do you mind to elaborate more? Because I tried `($cur_page/$per_page)+1` but it's not working