# How to change record numbers in the grid?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter pagination  here is my code

```
$config['base_url'] = $this->config->base_url().'users/allusers/';
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Prev';
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';   
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->usersmodel->getUsersCount();
    $config['per_page'] = 20;   
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);     
    $data['paging']=$this->pagination->create_links();      
    $data['query']=$this->usersmodel->getAllusers($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));
```

Now i need to add record numbers to the grid here is my grid code.

```
    $i=1;
    foreach ($query->result() as $row){
     echo $i; 
         echo $row->username;
         echo $row->name;
         echo $row->city;
         echo $row->address;        
     $i++;
     }
    ?>
```

Here the $i is always printing the numbers 1-20 even when i'm in second page. actually i need to print 20-40 
I need to know how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set $i to the value of the current page minus one, multiplied by the number of rows in a page:

Replace:

```
$i=1;
```

with

```
$i = ( $this->pagination->cur_page > 1 ) ? ( $this->pagination->cur_page - 1 )  * $config['per_page'] : 1 ;
```

If cur_page is inaccessible, try to extend the pagination class with something like this:

Create a file called MY_Pagination.php and put it in application/libraries/

Add this code to your extend pagination class;

```
class MY_Pagination extends CI_Pagination {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getCurrentPage() {
        return $this->cur_page;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to make sure the class extension prefix is set correctly to MY_ in the config.php (about line 109)

Then you can access it like so:

```
$i = ( $this->pagination->getCurrentPage() > 1 ) ? ( $this->pagination->getCurrentPage() - 1 )  * $config['per_page'] : 1 ;
```

I used and slightly modified some content from this question:

[How to echo page number with codeigniter pagination library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376279/how-to-echo-page-number-with-codeigniter-pagination-library)

Answer (score 1):

Set `$i` to the page number multiplied by the number of rows per page. Therefore, when you loop through to array, it will start at 0-20 on the first page, 20-40 on the second page.

However, with this method, you will need to make sure that the first page is 0, second page 1, etc...

```
$i = ($page_number - 1) * $config['per_page']; 
// $page_number may be $this->uri->segment(3) from what I can determine from your code.

foreach ($query->result() as $row){
    echo $i; 
    echo $row->username;
    echo $row->name;
    echo $row->city;
    echo $row->address;        
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: thanks Max_ i altered this code to $i = ($this->uri->segment(3)=="" ? 1 : $this->uri->segment(3)+1); this is working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code for pagination in any where........

There is an inbuilt Pagination class provided by codeIgniter. You can find it in user guide.

Define a start index variable in the function where u want to use pagination as zero.

```
 public function pagination($start_index = 0)
```

{

```
 $result = $this->model->get_results($data); //this $data is the argument which you are   passing to your model function. If you are using database to get results array.

 $items_per_page = 10;   //this is constant variable which you need to define

 $filtered_result = array_splice($result, $start_index, ITEM_PER_PAGE_USERS);

 $model['$filtered_result'] = $filtered_result;

 $total_rows = count($result);

$model['page_links'] = create_page_links  (base_url()."/controlelr_name/pagination",ITEM_PER_PAGE_USERS, $total_rows);

$this->load->view('controller_name/view_file_name', $model);
```

}

```
 function create_page_links($base_url, $per_page, $total_rows)
```

{

```
 $CI = & get_instance();
 $CI->load->library('pagination');

$config['base_url'] = $base_url;
$config['total_rows'] = $total_rows;
$config['per_page'] = $per_page; 

$CI->pagination->initialize($config); 

return $CI->pagination->create_links();
```

}